# Cognos 10.2.2 how to look at what reports are being sent to a specific recipient?

Tags: cognos

For Cognos 10.2.2 or Cognos 11
How can we look at what reports are being sent to a specific recipient?

Maybe there is an easy way to query the content store?
I did notice some third party tools (Motio) and any feedback/advice would also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know some basics of querying the Content Store, basic data exploration techniques, and SQL, so I won't go over that.

Look in CMOBJPROPS26.DELIVOPTIONS.  You'll need to parse the text.  There are several fields you may be looking at:

- to, cc, and bcc contain CAMID values that relate to your external
  directory namespace (?).  You can look these up on CMOBJPROPS33.
- toAddress, ccAddress, and bccAddress contain email addresses
  (user@domain.com).

You'll use CMOBJPROPS26 to join to the rest of the query by CMID.  The objects referenced by CMOBJPROPS26 are not reports.  In my environment, I have emails related to objects of these classes:

- agentTaskDefinition
- historyDetailRequestArguments
- jobDefinition
- jobStepDefinition
- reportVersion
- schedule

You'll need to figure out how each of those relates to reports.  You may be able to use CMOBJECTS.PCMID = CMOBJECTS.CMID or you may need to go through CMREFNOORD1, CMREFNOORD2, CMREFORD1, and/or CMREFORD2.